# Text replacing and formatting in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a little stuck with text replacing and formatting in ggplot2. This is my script:

```
require(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(extrafont)
font_import(pattern = 'Arch') 
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

df <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/moduVSmnc.csv")
breaks1 <- seq(1.85,2.5,by=0.05)

gg <- aggregate(mnc~cut(apl,breaks=breaks1,
labels=format(breaks1[-1],nsmall=2))+modu,df,mean)

colnames(gg)<- c("apl","modu","mnc")
gg$modu <- as.factor(gg$modu)

ggplot(gg) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x=modu,y=apl,fill=mnc))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(brewer.pal(10,"Spectral"))) +
  coord_fixed()+
  theme(legend.position = "right", axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 90, vjust = 0.25 , hjust = 1, colour = "grey50", family="Archer-Medium")
  ,axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, angle = 0, hjust = 1, colour = "grey50", family="Archer-Medium"))
```

Which produces this plot:

[image]

Now:

1. How to change the texts "modu", "apl" and "mnc" by "A", "B" and "C". I've been able do do it in the past, but I can't seem to make it work with this data set.

Also,

2. How to format A, B, C with the same font used for the axis values?

Thanks!

Comment: For the axis labels, use `+ xlab("text here") + ylab("text here")` (or change the underlying data by replacing the variable names with A, B & C as required)

Comment: To manually change the legend title you can use the `name` argument of the `discrete_scale`, i.e. `scale_fill_gradient(... name="legend name")` (you also may have a typo in your code on the `scale_fill_gradientn` line)

Comment: You can also do `labs(x="A", y="B", fill="C")`, which saves some typing.

Comment: Thanks! eipei10's comment works great! Now, I'm still wondering: how to apply the custom font to this new text?

Comment: Ok, with your help, I got it working for the most part. Now all I need is the right format for the legend (same as for axis titles). Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b3320ba8834996d3a710

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, thanks to the commenters and bits and pieces gathered here and there, I managed to get what I wanted.

Here's the script:

```
require(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(extrafont)
font_import(pattern = 'Arch') 
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

df <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/moduVSmnc.csv")
breaks1 <- seq(1.85,2.5,by=0.05)

gg <- aggregate(mnc~cut(apl,breaks=breaks1,
labels=format(breaks1[-1],nsmall=2))+modu,df,mean)

colnames(gg)<- c("apl","modu","mnc")
gg$modu <- as.factor(gg$modu)

ggplot(gg) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x=modu,y=apl,fill=mnc))+ labs(x="A", y="B", fill="C") +
 theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 0 , family="Archer-Semibold", colour="grey25", size=12),
axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 1 , family="Archer-Semibold", colour="grey25", size=12),
legend.title = element_text(vjust = 1 , family="Archer-Semibold", colour="grey25", size=12),
legend.text = element_text(vjust = 1 , family="Archer-Semibold", colour="grey25", size=12)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(brewer.pal(10,"Spectral"))) +
  coord_fixed()+
  theme(legend.position = "right", axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 90, vjust = 0.25 , hjust = 1, colour = "grey50", family="Archer-Medium")
  ,axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, angle = 0, hjust = 1, colour = "grey50", family="Archer-Medium"))
```

[image]

Thanks!